# cakephp 3, find all product children from category list

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I'm developing a simple web shop where I have a category list that has a has many relationship with categories.

```
+topcategory
 -subcategory 1
 -subcategory 2
....
```

When I click on top category I want to receive all products from the subcategories as well.

How to achieve this in CakePHP 3?

I use this for finding the products at the moment:

```
$products = $this->paginate($this->Products->find('threaded')
    ->where([
        'Categories.slug' => $slug
    ])
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Additional associations can be loaded to the paginated table by using the `contain` parameter:

```
$this->paginate['contain'] = [
    'Categories' => function (\Cake\ORM\Query $query) use ($slug) {
        return $query->where(['Categories.slug' => $slug]);
    }
];

$products = $this->paginate($this->Products);
```

**See also**

- [Joining Additional Associations](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/pagination.html#joining-additional-associations)

Comment: Hi Rayan, thx. I changed my code. But now I'm getting the topcategory products even when I click on subcategory2. Any reasons?

Comment: Edit your question adding your models relationships

Comment: @user3528258 I update the question, check again please